# Vb.net data misplaced

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Using visual studio 2010 I'm developing an vb.net application in which I need to store more than 10000 records in a table. The table format is

```
|empno |year |january|february| march |april |may |june |july |august |September |october |november  |december| total|
```

Sample data:

```
101 2010 10000 15000 25000
101 2011 15000 20000 35000
101 2012 20000 25000 45000
101 2013 25000 30000 55000
102 2008 1000  1500  2500
102 2009 1500  2000  3500
102 2010 10000 15000 25000
102 2011 15000 20000 35000
102 2012 20000 25000 45000
102 2013 25000 30000 55000
```

Now the problem is when I'm inserting the data into this table, it doesn't stored properly. I mean, It seems to be

```
102 2012 20000 25000 45000
101 2010 10000 15000 25000
101 2011 15000 20000 35000
101 2012 20000 25000 45000
101 2013 25000 30000 55000
102 2008 1000  1500  2500
102 2009 1500  2000  3500
102 2010 10000 15000 25000
102 2011 15000 20000 35000
102 2013 25000 30000 55000
```

In every set of data one of the year's record is stored at the top of the table. So, when I'm displaying records for a particular employee, it doesn't display it properly(I mean not in the order). Ex: for empno 102, the result is like

```
102 2012 20000 25000 45000
102 2008 1000  1500  2500
102 2009 1500  2000  3500
102 2010 10000 15000 25000
102 2011 15000 20000 35000
102 2013 25000 30000 55000
```

I think Sorting by year is not a solution. Because, it has many records for a year.

I checked for all the records. Only some of the record having this problem. I don't know anything about this problem and how to solve it. Can anyone what is the reason for this and how to avoid?

Thanks in advance

Edit: Code

```
If yodor1 <= 2015 Then
            up = 2015
        ElseIf yodor1 <= 2025 Then
            up = 2025
        ElseIf yodor1 <= 2035 Then
            up = 2035
        ElseIf yodor1 <= 2045 Then
            up = 2045
        End If

        con.Open()
        txt = "select * from pension where empno='" & TextBox5.Text & "' "
        cmd = New SqlCommand(txt, con)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read
            If yodor1 <= up Then
                flag = False
                display2.grid1.set_TextMatrix(a, 0, reader("year"))
                display2.grid1.set_TextMatrix(a, 1, reader("january"))
                display2.grid1.set_TextMatrix(a, 2, reader("february"))
                display2.grid1.set_TextMatrix(a, 3, reader("march"))
                display2.grid1.set_TextMatrix(a, 4, reader("april"))
                display2.grid1.set_TextMatrix(a, 5, reader("may"))
                display2.grid1.set_TextMatrix(a, 6, reader("june"))
                display2.grid1.set_TextMatrix(a, 7, reader("july"))
                display2.grid1.set_TextMatrix(a, 8, reader("august"))
                display2.grid1.set_TextMatrix(a, 9, reader("septemper"))
                display2.grid1.set_TextMatrix(a, 10, reader("october"))
                display2.grid1.set_TextMatrix(a, 11, reader("november"))
                display2.grid1.set_TextMatrix(a, 12, reader("december"))
                a = a + 1
                yodor1 = yodor1 + 1
            ElseIf yodor1 <= (up + 10) Then
                flag = False
                display2.grid2.set_TextMatrix(b, 0, reader("year"))
                display2.grid2.set_TextMatrix(b, 1, reader("january"))
                display2.grid2.set_TextMatrix(b, 2, reader("february"))
                display2.grid2.set_TextMatrix(b, 3, reader("march"))
                display2.grid2.set_TextMatrix(b, 4, reader("april"))
                display2.grid2.set_TextMatrix(b, 5, reader("may"))
                display2.grid2.set_TextMatrix(b, 6, reader("june"))
                display2.grid2.set_TextMatrix(b, 7, reader("july"))
                display2.grid2.set_TextMatrix(b, 8, reader("august"))
                display2.grid2.set_TextMatrix(b, 9, reader("septemper"))
                display2.grid2.set_TextMatrix(b, 10, reader("october"))
                display2.grid2.set_TextMatrix(b, 11, reader("november"))
                display2.grid2.set_TextMatrix(b, 12, reader("december"))
                b = b + 1
                yodor1 = yodor1 + 1
            ElseIf yodor1 <= (yodor + 19) Then
                flag = False
                DISPLAY3.grid2.set_TextMatrix(f, 0, reader("year"))
                DISPLAY3.grid2.set_TextMatrix(f, 1, reader("january"))
                DISPLAY3.grid2.set_TextMatrix(f, 2, reader("february"))
                DISPLAY3.grid2.set_TextMatrix(f, 3, reader("march"))
                DISPLAY3.grid2.set_TextMatrix(f, 4, reader("april"))
                DISPLAY3.grid2.set_TextMatrix(f, 5, reader("may"))
                DISPLAY3.grid2.set_TextMatrix(f, 6, reader("june"))
                DISPLAY3.grid2.set_TextMatrix(f, 7, reader("july"))
                DISPLAY3.grid2.set_TextMatrix(f, 8, reader("august"))
                DISPLAY3.grid2.set_TextMatrix(f, 9, reader("septemper"))
                DISPLAY3.grid2.set_TextMatrix(f, 10, reader("october"))
                DISPLAY3.grid2.set_TextMatrix(f, 11, reader("november"))
                DISPLAY3.grid2.set_TextMatrix(f, 12, reader("december"))
                f = f + 1
                yodor1 = yodor1 + 1
            ElseIf yodor1 < (yodor + 30) Then
                flag = False
                DISPLAY3.grid1.set_TextMatrix(c, 0, reader("year"))
                DISPLAY3.grid1.set_TextMatrix(c, 1, reader("january"))
                DISPLAY3.grid1.set_TextMatrix(c, 2, reader("february"))
                DISPLAY3.grid1.set_TextMatrix(c, 3, reader("march"))
                DISPLAY3.grid1.set_TextMatrix(c, 4, reader("april"))
                DISPLAY3.grid1.set_TextMatrix(c, 5, reader("may"))
                DISPLAY3.grid1.set_TextMatrix(c, 6, reader("june"))
                DISPLAY3.grid1.set_TextMatrix(c, 7, reader("july"))
                DISPLAY3.grid1.set_TextMatrix(c, 8, reader("august"))
                DISPLAY3.grid1.set_TextMatrix(c, 9, reader("septemper"))
                DISPLAY3.grid1.set_TextMatrix(c, 10, reader("october"))
                DISPLAY3.grid1.set_TextMatrix(c, 11, reader("november"))
                DISPLAY3.grid1.set_TextMatrix(c, 12, reader("december"))
                c = c + 1
                yodor1 = yodor1 + 1
            End If
        End While
        reader.Close()
        con.Close()
```

Comment: How are you getting the records from database? can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you better use parametrized queries to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) . Add `ORDER BY` clause to your query to sort the records by `year`

Try This :

```
txt = "select * from pension where empno= @empno ORDER BY year" 
cmd = New SqlCommand(txt, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", TextBox5.Text)
```

Comment: Actually, what is the problem?

Comment: @user2021114 what problem?

Comment: @user2021114 the query needed the `ORDER BY` clause to get you the records sorted by the year column.

Comment: @user2021114 just curious, why did you undo the UpVote ?

Comment: I checked, it seems to be same problem again. So I undo, Now fine. So redo

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the answer. I've used Clear() method

```
display2.grid1.clear()
display2.grid2.clear()
DISPLAY3.grid1.clear()
DISPLAY3.grid2.clear()
```

Now my problem is solved